# What does this error mean: Invalid compose project?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm learning how to run django rest with docker. I created an image, and I it's work when I use the command: **docker run -p 8000:8000 docker_django_tutorial**
But now I want to run this image through a docker-compose.yml file. Here is mine (it's based on a youtube vidéo, that why I don't understand why it doesn't work f
or me):

```
version: '3'

services:
  monapp:
    image: docker_django_tutorial
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    networks:
      - monreaseau

networks:
  monreseau:
```

When I run **docker-compose up** I've got the following error:

```
service "monapp" refers to undefined network monreaseau: invalid compose project
```

Just in case, here is my Dockerfile use for my image docker_django_tutorial:

```
#Use the Python3.7.2 container image
FROM python:3.7.2-stretch
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
#RUN python3 manage.py runserver
```

Comment: You have a typo `monreseau` , you missed an `a` in `monre(no a here)seau`

Comment: (Since [Compose provides a network named `default`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for you automatically, you can safely delete both `networks:` blocks to simplify the file.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you're anwsers.

Someone help me re-write my files like this:

Docker file:

```
#Use the Python3.7.2 container image
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
#CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:90"]
#RUN python3 manage.py runserver
```

docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'

```
services:
  monapp:
    image: docker_django_tutorial
    ports:
      - 90:90
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:90
```